# Mailcore: plainTextBodyRenderingOperationWithMessage returns nil

Tags: mailcore2

I'm using `plainTextBodyRenderingOperationWithMessage` to get summaries for my messages. I run it when the user logs in and then I run it again when the user scrolls to a certain point. The second time I run it it works perfectly. The first time I run it it only gets some message summaries. The `htmlString` returned for over half the messages is `nil` and I receive an error:

`Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=19 "An error occured while fetching messages in the requested folder." UserInfo=0x168a1260 {NSLocalizedDescription=An error occured while fetching messages in the requested folder`

I turned on connection logger but I don't get anything useful - it just prints the html for the messages it can get.

The strange part is that I'm getting these errors only the first time I make the call and the code for both is identical.

Below is my code.

```
MCOIMAPMessageRenderingOperation * op = [session plainTextBodyRenderingOperationWithMessage:message folder:self.folderpath];

[op start:^(NSString * htmlString, NSError * error) {
    NSLog(@"Error getting summary: %@", error);
}];
```

I have also tried `htmlBodyRenderingOperationWithMessage` with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have paid more heed to the error message. 'An error occurred while fetching messages **in the requested folder**'. The path I was passing as the folder parameter was `NULL`. It's still a little strange that, despite it being `NULL` the method managed to get some data successfully, however once I fixed that it worked correctly.

Comment: We could certainly add an assertion in those methods to check the value of folder. Would you mind sending a pull request?

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà Sure, I will look into it today or tomorrow.